# Get position of a cell in a grid based on latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I need a function in JavaScript that creates a custom sized grid over the world and outputs the x and y position of a cell based on latitude and longitude.

In this question is a somewhat similar function but it's in PHP and seems to be fixed on 100x100 meters: [Convert Latitude and Longitude values to a custom sized grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210963/convert-latitude-and-longitude-values-to-a-custom-sized-grid)

So the function I need should take latitude, longitude and the cell size in meters for the grid and should output the x and y position of the cell in which the coordinates are located.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick conversion from PHP to JS for you. PHP and JS are similar. You just needed Math. in front of a couple of the math functions and a function created to reproduce deg2rad function that PHP has.

JS doesn't make you preface vars with $ but it accepts them this way, so I didn't change any more of the function in your example link than was needed.

```js
function deg2rad (angle) {
    // http://jsphp.co/jsphp/fn/view/deg2rad
    // +   original by: Enrique Gonzalez
    // *     example 1: deg2rad(45);
    // *     returns 1: 0.7853981633974483
    return (angle / 180) * Math.PI;
}
function get_static_pointer_table_id($lat, $lng)
{
    $earth_circumference = 40000; // km

    $lat_bin = Math.round($lat / 0.0009);
    $lng_length = $earth_circumference * Math.cos(deg2rad($lat));
    $number_of_bins_on_lng = $lng_length * 10;
    $lng_bin = Math.round($number_of_bins_on_lng * $lng / 360);
    //the 'bin' unique identifier
    return $lat_bin + "_" + $lng_bin;
}

console.log(get_static_pointer_table_id(100, 99))
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm not really a calculus person, but I took a stab at it. I tried to convert the calculation to figure by meter and then update the final bin numbers by $m. The rounding changes things a bit between the first formula and the second that passes in 100m but perhaps it will do what you want. Again, just taking a stab, not sure it'll solve your problem.

```js
function deg2rad (angle) {
    // http://jsphp.co/jsphp/fn/view/deg2rad
    // +   original by: Enrique Gonzalez
    // *     example 1: deg2rad(45);
    // *     returns 1: 0.7853981633974483
    return (angle / 180) * Math.PI;
}
function get_static_pointer_table_id($lat, $lng, $m)
{
    $earth_circumference = 40000000; // m

    $lat_bin = Math.round($lat / 0.09);
    $lng_length = $earth_circumference * Math.cos(deg2rad($lat));
    $number_of_bins_on_lng = $lng_length /10000;
    $lng_bin = Math.round($number_of_bins_on_lng * $lng / 360);
    //the 'bin' unique identifier
    return $lat_bin * $m + "_" + $lng_bin *$m;
}

console.log(get_static_pointer_table_id(50, 18, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I define the size of the cells? 100x100 meters like from the other thread is way too much for me and it seems to be hardcoded.

Comment: I updated my answer. Not sure if this will solve your issue or not. I'm not a calculus person. But, doesn't hurt to take a stab at it.